# If :string is for text, how is checkbox data stored in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, checkbox

```
rails g migration add_anonymous_to_message anonymous:???
```

If I were adding a title etc to a message then I would put `rails g migration add_title_to_message title:string` but if :anonymous is a check box in the message submit form how do I add it to the database so that there are only two options: box checked=anonymous and box unchecked=username displayed?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you need another database column? What you could do is

- Add a column `username:string` which allows `NULL` values (default)
- Validate the model so that if `anonymous` is unchecked, saving a blank username is invalid
- Validate the model so that if `anonymous` is checked, the username is always saved as blank (`nil`), regardless of the form value
- When you check later on whether or not a message is anonymous you simply check for `message.username.nil?`

If for some reason you do need a separate DB column for `anonymous`, it should look like this:

`rails g migration add_anonymous_to_message anonymous:boolean`

Although not all RDBMS support `boolean` columns (MySQL doesn't), Rails takes care of this by generating a `TINYINT(1)` or similar column when you specify `boolean`, which is set to either `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use boolean type to store `anonymous` and string to store `username`:

```
rails g migration add_anonymous_and_username_to_message anonymous:boolean :default => false username:string
```